# Синонимизировать [chart.js] и [chartjs]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

На сайте есть две метки на одинаковую тему:

- [chart.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chart.js) (84 вопроса) *описания есть*
- [chartjs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chartjs) (22 вопроса) *описание нет*

Надо бы их синонимизировать, основная — [chart.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chart.js) (больше вопросов, и есть описание).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Готово.

```
updating post history, 25 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 22 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 17 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'chartjs': [chartjs] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 101
tag remapping of [chart.js] and [chartjs] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym chartjs -> chart.js was approved!
```